# Flutter Desktop - missing api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1.dll

Tags: windows, flutter, dll, flutter-desktop

During the work with Flutter on the desktop, I have run on a problem with missing api-ms-win-shcore-scaling-l1-1-1.dll. This problem occurs on a few computers with Windows 10. Parce of the PC's works well without any changes.

I was trying to update the Visual Studio to the latest version and it did not fix the problem. What should I do next with this?

For a reference, I also attach the screenshot of the alert dialog. (Sorry for the polish, but I had no possibility to change the language of the PC, to make a screenshot with English)

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% certain those machines are running Windows 10, and not Windows 7? That should be available from 8.1 forward, and the only reports I've seen of this issue are from Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that this occurs for the windows 10. It started occurring since the latest update of the Flutter (if this changes anything), before that the same machine was working correctly without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a windows 7 Issue dude, this DLL is available in Windows 10